# Why do my Spring Data MongoDB repositories fail to bootstrap after an upgrade to the latest version?

Tags: spring-data, java-8, spring-data-mongodb

I recently updated a small project to Java 8. This project uses `spring-data-mongodb`.
I upgraded all spring dependency versions to their latest stable version. `spring-data-mongodb` is running on `1.5.2.RELEASE`.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Whenever I start the service, I get a MappingException for java.lang.Object.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
15:21:51.177 [main] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pageableIdsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:600) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:389) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:869) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341) [jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:296) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334) [jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497) [jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:365) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:76) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:543) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:167) [jetty-maven-plugin-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:144) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:83) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
```

Where is this `java.lang.Object` coming from and why can't it be mapped correctly?

I debugged the library and it appears that the `java.lang.Object` class is passed more than once.. perhaps once for Java 8 and once for another version? As you can see, I'm running out of ideas :).

The most surprising thing to me was that by Googling this issue I couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Would you mind posting the root exception?

Comment: @OliverGierke I've added the full stacktrace, let me know if you need more details!

Answer (score 5):

From the exception it looks like the scanning for Spring Data repositories is picking up an intermediate repository that's not intended to become a real repository instance, but rather contains some generic declaration your other repositories define concrete types for.

This can be solved by annotating the `PageableIdsRepository`with `@NoRepositoryBean`. The details of that are explained in the [corresponding section of the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning).

The reason you see that pop up now is that you've probably been on a version of Spring Data MongoDB before that didn't instantiate repositories eagerly so that as long as nobody actually injected a `PageableIdsRepository` it would've not been created. We've changed that at some point to eager instantiation this is the default for other Spring beans as well.

Comment: Hi, no need to add @NoRepositoryBean. This happens when your repository is defined with a generic type: <br/>public interface MyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID> <br/>The generic T type is the problem. If possible, try to make it extends a class:<br/> <T extends MyClass, ID extends Serializable> <br/> Hope this will help.

Comment: On the contrary, @OliverGierke's solution is perfect if you aren't instantiating your own repository beans.